# Access Javascript Variable in php base_url

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am using AJAX and I'm getting the data from the database as Javascript variables. Now, in a table, I want to print an image using php base_url.
The problem is the image is not showing.
 Here is my code: everything is printing except the picture

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       showAllEmployee();
        function showAllEmployee(){
        $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '<?php echo site_url('Welcome/showAllEmployee') ?>',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                                var html = '';
                    var i;

                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){


                        html +='<tr>'+
                                    '<td> <img class="size1"  src="<?php echo base_url("/uploads/university/data[i].image")?>" /></td>'+

                                    '<td>'+data[i].name+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].division+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].location+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].min_hsc+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].ad+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].email+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>';
                    }
                    $('#showdata').html(html);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Could not get Data from Database');
                }
            });
        }
        }
        )
        </script>
```

Comment: just move that out of the php block.

Comment: or when you return the data, return the whole url.

Comment: Can you show your image url when it is printed on a page? You can verify this using firebug or developer tools in any popular web browser.

Comment: '<td> <img class="size1"  src="<?php echo base_url("/uploads/university/")?>data[i].image" /></td>'+
                             wrote like that, but not working

Answer (score 1):

I'd say something like this:

`'<td> <img class="size1" src="<?php echo base_url("/uploads/university/")?>' + data[i].image + '"/></td>'`

Answer (score 0):

You have not use javascript code directly with php. Please see below code. I hope it will works for you.

```
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
       document.cookie = "image =" + data[i].image;
     <?php
       $image= @$_COOKIE['image'];
     ?> 
                    html +='<tr>'+
                                '<td> <img class="size1"  src="<?php echo base_url("/uploads/university/".$image)?>" /></td>'+

                                '<td>'+data[i].name+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].division+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].location+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].min_hsc+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].ad+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].email+'</td>'+
                            '</tr>';
                }
```

Comment: @shawn Check your console and find what error occured? and let me know!